# osm2pgsql error Trying to import .osm to postGis on AWS

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to import osm data using osm2pgsql onto an aws rds instance. I get an error saying `Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Open failed for 'insights_poi': No such file or directory` but I am providing all the necessary files.

Locally, I'm running `osm2pgsql -c -d insights_poi -U insights_poi -H beta.cyrrprcqeykj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -S default.style austin_texas.osm.pbf -W insights_poi -r .pbf`

and the `default.style` and the `austin_texas.osm.pbf` file are in the same folder I'm running this from. Why is it saying it can't find the file?

It actually gets pretty far after I run the command

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `-W`, the docs specified `-w forces password prompt` which I treated as a parameter. so The error `Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Open failed for 'insights_poi': No such file or directory` was a result of `-W insights_poi` since nothing was really expected after the `-W`, it was treating the `insights_poi` value as the name of a file there that didn't exist.

In the end this did it, `osm2pgsql -c -d insights_poi -U insights_poi -H beta.cyrrprcqeykj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -r .pbf -S default.style -W austin_texas.osm.pbf`